# How to make database of admins in discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

Hi i try to make command which will send admins and moderators on the server for example
!admins
@Administrator
SasaIgor
Jeff Bezos
@Moderators
Steve Jobs
Android

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question seems vague and I'm not sure I understand what you want to accomplish. Could you add some details, screenshots or even code snippets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to know who are the admins/moderators in the server, this should help: https://iqcode.com/code/javascript/discordjs-get-all-members-with-role

Then basically push every users' name to a string like this `<@userID>` and send it

(psst, DiscordJS v13 exists)

Comment: no djs v12 only